# how to configure postfix to deliver emails to an app?

Tags: postfix

greetings all
is it possible to configure postfix to deliver emails to an app
that perform some action on this emails.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds more like a question for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/faq).

This being said, [Postfix pipes](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) are probably what you need:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    The  pipe(8)  daemon  processes  requests from the Postfix
>    queue manager to deliver messages  to  external  commands.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

### main.cf

Assuming you are on a virtual setup, define your virtual_transport in main.cf :

```
virtual_transport : myowncustomizedtransport
```

### master.cf

then in master.cf define how `myowncustomizedtransport` works. As @Bruno already mentionned, you should use the Pipe transport agent (and read its man page) to deliver all virtual email through your application.

```
myowncustomizedtransport  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/myapplication with some arguments (read man pipe to get a list of arguments you could get like $recipient and $client_address or $size)
```